# How to label each bar in asp.net chart with month name

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, charts

I have the following chart output and the part of code to generate it. IsLabelAutofit=false but still it is not showing all the months label.

```
<asp:Series Name="Series1" XValueMember="xDate" YValueMembers="TimePerDay"    ChartArea="ChartArea2" ChartType="column" YValuesPerPoint="6" IsValueShownAsLabel="true" LabelFormat="{0:N0}" >
                    </asp:Series>
                </Series>
                <ChartAreas>
                    <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea2">
                        <AxisY Interval="450">
                            <MajorGrid Enabled="true" LineColor="lightgray" />
                            <StripLines>
                                <asp:StripLine TextAlignment="Near" BorderDashStyle="Solid" BorderColor="#0000ff" BorderWidth="2" BackColor="#0000ff" />
                                <asp:StripLine BorderWidth="5" />
                            </StripLines>
                        </AxisY>
                        <AxisX IsLabelAutoFit="false" TitleForeColor="black">
                            <LabelStyle Format="MMMM" Angle="-90" IsEndLabelVisible="true" />


                            <MajorGrid Enabled="false" />
                        </AxisX>
                    </asp:ChartArea>
                </ChartAreas>

            </asp:Chart>
```

[image]

Comment: What are you using in Web.config?

Comment: The two columns data is input to the chart from a query. Any specific?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `Interval` and `IntervalType` as shown below:

```
        <ChartAreas>
            <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1">
                <AxisX IsLabelAutoFit="False">
                    <MajorTickMark Interval="1" IntervalType="Months" />
                    <LabelStyle Angle="-90" Format="MMMM" Interval="1" IntervalType="Months" />
                </AxisX>
            </asp:ChartArea>
        </ChartAreas>
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, you are almost there. The one small problem also visible in your chart is that there is no tick in front of other months. Is it possible to add them to the February, March, May, June, August, September, November and December?

Comment: Is there any thing for weekwise? I will post another question but just wana know.

Comment: Can you have a look of my question and give your suggestion please. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32059936/how-to-label-the-weekly-chart-in-asp-net-chart-control

Comment: I don't have an immediate good suggestion. `DateTime` does not convert straight into a "week" value. You would have to use `Calendar` to do that calculation and get the week of the year.  It is a bit more complicated because it involves culture information, leap year, what your convention is for the first day of the week, etc.... :O)