# How to label the weekly chart in ASP.Net chart control

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following chart which shows user walking per week. At the moment it shows the dates. Is there any professional way to show weekwise data. 
[image]

The following code is used to generate the chart

```
 <asp:Chart ID="Chart2" runat="server" Height="450" Palette="Fire" CssClass="col-md-12">
                <Series>
                    <asp:Series Name="Series1" XValueMember="xdate" YValueMembers="TimePerDay" ChartArea="ChartArea2" ChartType="column" YValuesPerPoint="6" IsValueShownAsLabel="true" LabelFormat="{0:N0}" IsXValueIndexed="true">
                    </asp:Series>
                </Series>
                <ChartAreas>
                    <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea2">
                        <AxisY Interval="60">
                            <MajorGrid Enabled="true" LineColor="lightgray" />
                            <StripLines>
                                <asp:StripLine TextAlignment="Near" BorderDashStyle="Solid" BorderColor="#0000ff" BorderWidth="2" BackColor="#0000ff" />
                                <asp:StripLine BorderWidth="5" />
                            </StripLines>
                        </AxisY>
                        <AxisX IsLabelAutoFit="false" TitleForeColor="black" Interval="1">
                            <LabelStyle Format="dd-MM-yy" Angle="-90" IsEndLabelVisible="true" />
                            <MajorGrid Enabled="false" />
                        </AxisX>
                    </asp:ChartArea>
                </ChartAreas>
                                </asp:Chart>
```

Comment: If you were to show weekly data, let's say, between Dec-2014 and Jan-2015, what exactly would you expect to see as labels in your X-Axis?

Comment: I am not sure but any sensible way will be ok.

Answer (score 1):

I have always used weeknumbering in excel when trying to push week data into graphs, however your x axis will effectively need to be a string something like 'yyyy-ww' or 2015-32 such that it will sort and order order correctly in the chart.

[Get the correct week number of a given date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11154673/get-the-correct-week-number-of-a-given-date)